# Python .avi to .mp4

Tags: python, ffmpeg, video-processing

I need some python code for this function. I have installed ffmpeg in Ubuntu.

```
def convert_avi_to_mp4(avi_file.avi):
   mp4_file = None
   #some code to do the job
   return mp4_file
```

Thank you

Answer (score 6, accepted):

you can do something like this..

```
import os

def convert_avi_to_mp4(avi_file_path, output_name):
    os.popen("ffmpeg -i '{input}' -ac 2 -b:v 2000k -c:a aac -c:v libx264 -b:a 160k -vprofile high -bf 0 -strict experimental -f mp4 '{output}.mp4'".format(input = avi_file_path, output = output_name))
    return True
```

Comment: This didn't work for me and I kept getting "No such file or directory".
I fixed this by removing the single quotes.